# any hierarchical list editor (Vim / MS Word / LaTeX / Lisp / ..)

Tags: microsoft-word, vim, latex, xml, elisp

We have **hierarchically ordered items** stored in a textfile and **idented with tabulator**.

  colors
    red
    green
    blue

  computers
    Linux
    Mac
    Windows

  numbers
    one
    two
    three

It must have **guiding lines** on the side, because we are dealing with **very long lists** and it's impossible to track the level when scrolling down without lines.

```
TREE
+---colors
¦   +---blue
¦   +---green
¦   +---red
+---computers
¦   +---linux
¦   +---mac
¦   +---windows
+---numbers
    +---one
    +---three
    +---two
```

See [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X8TQ.jpg) for illustration.
How to conveniently edit and reorder such lists, in a **WYSIWYG** fashion?
One should be able to move items up and down levels. Also apply alphabetical **sorting** to a tree branch.

Is there a simple and appropriate **language, software tool or workflow** for this?

MS Word is a bit of an overstretch. Word uses only styling and doesn't export to data.
XML is the best way to store nested data but it's unusably hard to edit.
If there isn't a solution we will have to code one. But that would be quite an investment.

Comment: I'm no expert on it, but I'd guess that `org-mode` in Emacs has something to offer you in this regard.  Maybe not just as you imagine it now, but possibly something that you can use (and that might be better than what you envision). With luck, some Org mode expert will chime in with a straightforward solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called an outliner. Google will give you dozens of results for every platform. Read their documentation, try the ones that seem to satisfy your requirements and make *your* choice.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, you just need to come up with a proper way of *folding* (easiest manually with `{{{` markers, but most comfortable with a custom `'foldexpr'`), and you'll get the guiding lines for free (by setting `'foldcolumn'`), and can easily move entire (closed) folds with the standard yank / delete / paste commands.